# One pod/job per kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to schedule periodically kubernetes jobs (with different images)

These jobs are required to run on a node with GPU support (1 GPU device)

Currently If I create two jobs at the same time - the pods will be scheduled both on the same node - while only one pod will have access to GPU device

Is there a way to configure nodes/pods so that scheduler only places one pod per node and once it is completed places next job ?

Comment: I assume you need to schedule a job, right? And not a pod that will remain active even after the job is done. Also, do you need to schedule it/them at a fixed or recurring time?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà yes I'm using kubernetes jobs for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using suggestion from @Calum Halpin  with **Extended Resources for a Node**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/

1. patch the node and add 1 "gpu" to capacity:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
--request PATCH \
--data '[{"op": "add", "path": "/status/capacity/gpu", "value": "1"}]' \
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/status
```

2. Then for your container set resource request for 1 gpu:

```
    resources:
      requests:
        gpu: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set an inter-pod anti-affinity as described in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

> Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity rules take the form "this Pod should (or, in the case of anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running one or more Pods that meet rule Y", where X is a topology domain like node, rack, cloud provider zone or region, or similar and Y is the rule Kubernetes tries to satisfy.

> Similar to node affinity are two types of Pod affinity and anti-affinity as follows:
>
> - requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution
> - preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution

> Consider the following Pod spec:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: with-pod-affinity
> spec:
>   affinity:
>     podAffinity:
>       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
>       - labelSelector:
>           matchExpressions:
>           - key: security
>             operator: In
>             values:
>             - S1
>         topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
>     podAntiAffinity:
>       preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
>       - weight: 100
>         podAffinityTerm:
>           labelSelector:
>             matchExpressions:
>             - key: security
>               operator: In
>               values:
>               - S2
>           topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
>   containers:
>   - name: with-pod-affinity
>     image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
> ```

Comment: wow, this is so counter intuitive... I really hope there is a pimplier way

Comment: What are you finding counter-intuitive? You can set an anti-affinity on your pod/job template so that they won't be scheduled together with a matching pod/job.

Comment: well it's the 20 extra lines... what would be nice is to be able to mark a node with some custom resource values (like GPU=1) and then use it as resourses/limits

Comment: Pydev UA what @CalumHalpin suggested is the best and the suggested way. Even though the code is lengthy it performs the required functionality perfectly i.e scheduling certain pods on a certain node and in a certain fashion. Once you go through the documentation provided by him you might find it very easy to understand. FYR I'm posting the documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) again and since you asked for a simpler way posting a different solution

Comment: @PydevUA You could also look at extended resources: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/. It isn't something I've used but you may be able to get it to behave as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are preferring to use a simple way you can use nodeSelector for selecting your desired node using the node labels and use queueSort for scheduling pods one after another. In short you are defining pods with certain labels to run on a certain node that too on a priority basis. This [document](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2021-12/custom-k8s-scheduler/) gives you a better understanding for achieving your desired functionality.